# Meteor - preventDefault not preventing default

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm busy with David Turnbull's - Your first Meteor Application. Everything works up to the point where I try and add a new player to the list via a form. My problem is that preventDefault is not preventing the form from trying to submit and reloading the page. return false doesn't work either.

Any ideas why this will be happening?

Thanks

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  //Helpers
  Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    'player': function() {
      return PlayersList.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
    },
    'playerCount': function() {
      return PlayersList.find().count();
    },
    'selectedClass': function() {
      var playerId = this._id;
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      if(playerId == selectedPlayer) {
        return 'selected'
      }
    },
    'showSelectedPlayer': function() {
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      return PlayersList.findOne(selectedPlayer);
    }
  });

  //Events
  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click .player': function() {
      var playerId = this._id;
      Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
    },
    'click .increment': function() {
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      var increaseBy = document.getElementById('increase-by').value;
      var isNumber = /^\d+$/.test(increaseBy);
      if(increaseBy != '' && isNumber) {
        PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: +increaseBy}});
      }
    },
    'click .decrement': function() {
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      var decreaseBy = document.getElementById('decrease-by').value;
      PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: -decreaseBy}});
    },
    'submit #new-player': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var playerNameVar = event.target.playerName.value;

      if(playerNameVar != '') {
        PlayersList.insert({
          name: playerNameVar,
          score:0
        });
      }
    }  
  });
}
```

Template

```
<template name="addPlayerForm">

<div id="add-player" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    <h2>Add a player</h2>
    <p class="lead">Add another player to the leaderboard</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 column small-centered">
            <form id="new-player">
                <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="small-8 column">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Player name" name="playerName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-4 column">
                        <input type="submit" class="button postfix" value="add player">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</template>
```

Comment: Can you include your template as well?

Comment: I added the template and updated according to you answer but there is no change. Form still submits and refreshes the page.

Comment: Just updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never read the book, and I don't know what your template looks like, but the problem is likely due to a selector issue.

Maybe try assigning an id to your form and mapping the submit event to that id:

```
// html file
<Template name="leaderboard">
  <form id="new-player">
    <input type="text" name="playerName">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</Template>

// js file
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'submit #new-player': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
  }
});
```

**Edit**

Maybe try changing `Template.leaderboard.events` to `Template.addPlayerForm.events`.

Comment: That was the problem. I was using the event for the wrong template. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Handy tip I discovered (because some days are dumb days) if you place the `event.preventDefault()` at the end of the function implementation and an unhandled exception occurs in your earlier code, the form will submit and cause the page to refresh before you see the exception in the log (and before the default is prevented). Call `event.preventDefault()` before your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made the same mistake as the poster and I am putting the correct code here:

In html file:

```
<template name="addPlayerForm">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="playerName">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Player">
  </form>
</template>
```

In js file:

```
Template.addPlayerForm.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Form submitted");
        console.log(event.type);
    }
});
```